Definite integral involving Bessel function: $\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{J_n^2(z\sin\theta)}{\sin\theta}\,d\theta$
While reading Jackson's Classical Electrodynamics (section on diffraction through a circular aperture in normal incidence) I ran into the following integral relation for Bessel functions which I am unable to prove nor find another reference to:
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{J_n^2(z\sin\theta)}{\sin\theta}\,d\theta = \int_0^{2z}\frac{J_{2n}(t)}{t}\,dt$$
By a change of variables $u = \sin\theta$, the LHS can be transformed into
$$\int_0^1\frac{J_n^2(zu)}{u\sqrt{1-u^2}}\,du$$
I cannot find a relation between $J_{2n}$ and $J_n$ that would allow me to further transform this integral into the RHS.
Exploring a bit with WolframAlpha, it seems that the definite integrals actually have a closed form in terms of $J_n(2z)$ and $J_{n+1}(2z)$ and rational functions of $z$. In particular when $n=1$, we seem to have $$\int_0^1\frac{J_1^2(zu)}{u\sqrt{1-u^2}}\,du = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2z}J_1(2z)$$
However the corresponding indefinite integrals do not seem to be expressible in elementary functions or Bessel functions $J_n$.
This gave me the idea of computing derivatives of the LHS with respect to $z$ using differentiation under the integral sign and showing that it satisfies a Bessel-type differential equation, while simplifying the occurences of $J_n'$ and $J_n''$ using their own Bessel differential equation and recurrence relations. However what I get with this approach and some simplifications along the way is:
$$I(z) = \int_0^1\frac{J_1^2(zu)}{u\sqrt{1-u^2}}\,du$$
$$I'(z) = \frac{2n}{z}I(z) - 2\int\frac{J_n(zu)J_{n+1}(zu)}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\,du$$
$$I''(z) = \frac{2n-1}{z}I'(z) + 2\int_0^1\frac{uJ_{n+1}^2(zu) - uJ_n^2(zu)}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\,du$$
$$I'''(z) = \frac{4n-1}{z}I''(z) - \frac{4n^2-1}{z^2}I'(z) + 8\int_0^1\frac{u^2J_n(zu)J_{n+1}(zu)}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\,du - \frac{8n+4}{z}\int_0^1\frac{uJ_{n+1}^2(zu)}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\,du$$
There always remain some terms that I cannot simplify further, and due to the presence of the $u^2$ in the numerator of the third term for $I'''(z)$, I cannot combine it with the earlier expression for $I'(z)$. So in the end I am unable to set up a differential equation for $I(z)$.
I still think that could be a promising approach but I am clearly missing some trick. At first sight, integration by parts doesn't help because the denominator of $\sqrt{1-u^2}$ will also change.
I am at a loss for other ideas, so any help would be appreciated, even if only for the case $n = 1$.

For anyone interested, by looking through Gradshteyn&Ryzhik and then Tables of Integral Transforms by Erdélyi, I also managed to find another reference to these integrals in this paper: BAILEY, W. N. (1938). SOME INTEGRALS INVOLVING BESSEL FUNCTIONS. The Quarterly Journal of Mathematics, os-9(1), 141–147. doi:10.1093/qmath/os-9.1.141

We can show that both integrals have the same series representation.
I'm assuming that $n$ and $z$ are greater than zero.

$$ \begin{align} &\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{J_{n}^{2}(z \sin \theta)}{\sin \theta} \, \mathrm d \theta \\&\overset{\clubsuit}{=}  \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{\sin \theta} \left(\frac{z \sin \theta}{2} \right)^{2n} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\Gamma (2n+2k+1)}{\Gamma(2n+k+1)} \frac{1}{k!\Gamma(n+k+1)^{2}} \left(-\frac{z^{2} \sin^{2} \theta}{4} \right)^{k} \mathrm d \theta \\ &= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!}\left(\frac{z}{2} \right)^{2k+2n} \frac{\Gamma(2n+2k+1)}{\Gamma(2n+k+1)} \frac{1}{\Gamma(n+k+1)^{2}} \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sin^{2k+2n-1}(\theta) \, \mathrm d \theta \\ &\overset{\spadesuit}{=}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!}\left(\frac{z}{2} \right)^{2k+2n} \, \frac{\Gamma(2n+2k+1)}{\Gamma(2n+k+1)} \frac{1}{\Gamma(n+k+1)^{2}} \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}  \frac{\Gamma(n+k)}{\Gamma(n+k+ \tfrac{1}{2})} \\ &\overset{\diamondsuit}{=} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!}\left(\frac{z}{2} \right)^{2k+2n}  \frac{1}{\Gamma(2n+k+1)} \, 2^{2n+2k} \, \frac{1}{\Gamma(n+k+1)}\frac{\Gamma(n+k)}{2} \\ &= \color{red}{\frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!} \frac{1}{\Gamma(2n+k+1)} \frac{z^{2k+2n}}{n+k}} \end{align}$$

$\clubsuit$ https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.8#E3
$\spadesuit$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Other_identities_and_formulas
$\diamondsuit$ Duplication formula for the gamma function

$$ \begin{align} \int_{0}^{2z} \frac{J_{2n}(t)}{t} \, \mathrm dt &=  \int_{0}^{1} \frac{J_{2n}(2zu)}{u} \, \mathrm du \\ &= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{u}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{k! \Gamma(2n+k+1)} \left(\frac{2zu}{2} \right)^{2k+2n} \, \mathrm du \\ &= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!} \frac{1}{\Gamma(2n+k+1)} z^{2k+2n} \int_{0}^{1} u^{2k+2n-1} \, \mathrm du \\ &= \color{red}{\frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!} \frac{1}{\Gamma(2n+k+1)} \frac{z^{2k+2n}}{n+k}} \end{align}$$

Thanks this looks like a straightforward derivation. The first identity (from the DLMF link) was not obvious to verify, but it follows from Vandermonde's identity after multiplying out the power series. The rest was clear enough.
